# parameter_unknown created.gte cannot search

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-8, invoice, laravel-cashier

"error": {
"code": "parameter_unknown",
"doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
"message": "Received unknown parameter: created.gte. Did you mean created?",
"param": "created.gte",
"type": "invalid_request_error"
}

Comment: Which endpoint are you hitting? Can you share the code that made the API call?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the `created.gte` into an associative array. Here is a solution for native PHP Stripe library. It returns all invoices for the last week it does work in Laravel as well.

```
$stripeClient   = new StripeClient( $this->stripeKey ); 
$stripeClient->invoices->all([[ 'created' => ['gte' => (time() - 604800)] ]])->data
```